# opencl: asynchronous memory-obj sharing between kernels (of the same context, device)

Tags: pointers, memory, opencl, sharing

Is it valid to share the same memory object between 2 kernels without any synchronization in OCL 1.2? 
i.e. I want to create a memory object, do a copy_host_ptr and pass it to 2 kernels as pointers for simultaneous access, mainly read.

Im using the same device/context/program etc for both kernels and I only care about offsets in the memory. i.e. I dont care if the base address of the mem-obj in the 2 kernels are the same or not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a single command queue, yes, because then your kernels run one after another and never access the memory at the same time.

If you are using multiple command queues, which under the right conditions can enable simultaneous execution of kernels on certain hardware, then you should only do this for a read-only buffer. If the buffer is written to by either kernel then I think the read results are undefined, and if written to by both kernels even more so.

Comment: The proper way, even if only using one command queue (which under some conditions it can even run parallel jobs), is to set the flags to the buffer objects. That makes the OpenCL driver take care for you not to use the same buffer for writing(or read/writing) in 2 kernels at the same time.

Comment: @DarkZeros, I've never been clear on what the conditions might be where a subsequent kernel could start executing before a previous one finished. It makes sense that it could be possible, given idle compute units near the end of a job. Would the runtime have to look at the buffer and image objects being used to determine if there are dependencies?